# Ipyleaflet WMS get attributes on click

Tags: python, leaflet, interactive, wms, ipyleaflet

I have a WMS layer that I display with `ipyleaflet`.
I would like to print the attributes of the figure on which I click.

I know QGIS does that under the hood but I didn't manage to access the code doing that.
It is calling `wgs.getfeatureinfo()` but I haven't been successful in reproducing it.

Do you know how that could be handled ?

Here is my code to display the map:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, WMSLayer, basemaps
from ipywidgets import HTML

# Create a function to handle click events

def click_handler(event=None, feature=None, id=None, properties=None):
    info = wms.get_feature_info()
    print(info)

# Define the WMS layer
wms_url = "https://glims.org/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&"
wms = WMSLayer(
    url=wms_url,
    layers='GLIMS:RGI',
    transparent=True,
    format='image/png'
)

# Create the map
m = Map(basemap=basemaps.CartoDB.Positron, center=(38.491, -95.712), zoom=4)

# Add the WMS layer to the map
m.add_layer(wms)

m
```